# Eigen C++ matrix multiplication between MatrixXd and VectorXd

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra, eigen

So below is my code and as you can see I am trying to multiply a square matrix MatrixXd with vectorXd.

When I try this, I get the following error: 
"invalid operands to binary expression ('const typename ProductReturnType > >, Matrix >::Type' (aka 'const GeneralProduct

I do not know what is going wrong. I am sorry if this is a bad question, but please help!

```
void calcMinPortfolio(int num_ofStocks, Eigen::MatrixXd& covMatrix, Eigen::VectorXd& weights){

Eigen::MatrixXd identityMat;
identityMat.resize(num_ofStocks, num_ofStocks);
identityMat.Identity();
weights = (covMatrix.inverse() * identityMat) / (identityMat.transpose() * covMatrix.inverse() * identityMat);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems:

1 - The way you construct the identity, you cannot use `.Identity()` on a dynamic matrix (only on compile-size specified size). Simply use the one-liner

```
Eigen::MatrixXd identityMat = Eigen::MatrixXd::Identity(num_ofStocks, num_ofStocks);
```

2 - The denominator is a general matrix product (a type), so you cannot divide a matrix by it. What do you mean by division of a matrix by another one? Use `.inverse()` for the denominator if this is what you want. Next, multiplying by identities doesn't make any sense unless `covMatrix` is a scalar, which is not.

PS: even if the denominator is a a size `1 x 1` matrix, it is still a matrix type, and not a scalar, so you cannot divide a matrix by it. If you want to divide it by the scalar represented by the matrix, then use `your_expresion(0)` to extract the scalar from the `1 x 1` matrix.

Comment: yeah.. i'm an idiot. the identityMat is suppose to be a vector of 1... but this definitely helps me for future problems. Thanks a lot!